# streamline processing of large files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Is there a way to streamline process large or excel files in pandas without taking up large amounts of memory?

What I do right now is load the file like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('SUPERLARGEFILE.csv', index_col=0, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False)

Perform some task

data.to_csv('Results.csv', sep=',')
```

If I was working on a computer with low amounts of memory. Is there a way which I can stream and process large datafiles with a iterative function to do something like:

```
   Load first 1000 rows, store this in memory

   Perform some task

   Save data

   Load next 1000 rows, over write this in memory

   perform task

   append to save file
```

Comment: see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk; this is a pretty common idiom. also very efficient to store as HDF5 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the chunksize argument to your code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('SUPERLARGEFILE.csv', index_col=0, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=Fals, chunksize=10)

result = []
for chunk in data:  # get chunks of 10 rows each
   result.append(chunk.mean())
# do something with res e.g. res = DataFrame(res).to_csv("result.csv")
```

Comment: Not sure but it looks like your code overrides Results.csv each time.

Comment: Edited, now the code shows the correct use of chunksize.